# Should I use delete and findIndex or filter to remove and item from an immutable.js List?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, pointfree

I'm considering how to best use Immutable.js. I saw some code like this:

```
state.update('something', something =>
 something.delete(
   something.findIndex(x => x.id === 1)
 )
)
```

And it seems to me like this code could be written much cleaner using filter:

```
state.update('something', something =>
 something.filter(x => x.id !== 1)
)
```

It could even be point-free:

```
propEq = k => v => x => x[k] === v
state.update('something', propEq('x', 1))
```

Are there any significant performance trade-offs here?

If `delete` + `findIndex` is demonstrably more performant, is there a clean, point-free way of writing this code?

Answer (score 1):

I like your filter approach. I might tweak the predicate to use [filterNot()](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/filterNot), though that's just personal taste more than anything:

```
state.update('something', something =>
  something.filterNot(x => x.id === 1)
)
```

The only perf concern is that filtering means you have to iterate over the whole list, no matter what. This isn't a big deal for smaller lists, but with larger lists, the perf degradation might be noticeable.

For example, in a list of 10,000 items, `findIndex()` probably won't iterate 10,000 times whereas `filter()` will always iterate 10,000 times.

So I would stick with the cleaner code, switching to `findIndex()` and `delete()` if `filter()` doesn't scale with your application data.

Answer (score 1):

As Adam stated, `findIndex` won't probably iterate over the whole list, but my recommendation would be to use Map instead of List with `id` being the key. Then you have time complexity of O(1) and deleting entries is much more cleaner and readable as well.